# Need to update a single item quantity in cart data collection foreach loop in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to update the quantity of single product in whole cart coming from foreach loop and then save cart.

```
         foreach($quoteModel->getAllVisibleItems() as $it){
        $itemid=$it->getId();
        $sku=$it->getSKU();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
         $cartId=$cart->getQuote()->getId();
        $cartitems = $quoteModel->getItemById( $it->getId());
        $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
        $cartitems->setitemId($it->getId());

    }

    $cartitems->save();  // Add code
    $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
    $quoteModel->setItems($quoteItems);
    $quoteModel->collectTotals();
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to update the qty of particualr product in cart, right?

Comment: yes i want to update quantity of single product.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

class Yourcustomcontroller extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $quoteRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $cartId = $cart->getQuote()->getId();

        $itemId = 32; //You need to take your Item Id
        $itemQty = 5; //You need to set your qty

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $cartitems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
        $cartitems->setitemId($itemId);
        $cartitems->setqty($itemQty);

        $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
        $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        $quote->collectTotals();

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually quote data is coming from foreach loop and i am unable to setqty for a single product there.

Comment: You need to identift the proper ItemId and set proper qty into that one.

Comment: If answer help then Upvote and accept as solutions, so it will help other in community.